# Convert Queryset to dictionary with values for JSON

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I have written an Ajax call to return actor names. Everything works fine except for serialization.

**Model**

```
class ActorManager (models.Manager):
    def actor_like(self, query):
        actor_list = self.values('name', 'id').filter(name__icontains=query)
        # actor_list = self.filter(name__icontains=query) <-- this works. but I need 'values'
        return actor_list
```

**view.py**

```
def search(request, types, query):
    lists = Actor.objects.actor_like(query)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', lists)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

the above throws error,

AttributeError at /search/actor/bal/

**'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'**

whereas the model query "values" works fine. The below works fine,

```
actor_list = self.filter(name__icontains=query)
```

I need "values" in order to reduce the data transfer. How can I achieve this?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to serialize queryset object just add in a dict as data['lists'] = lists and you can use lists as an object in your template.

Comment: Tanveer is correct if you're making an ajax call that is using json the serialization should be done automatically from the queryset that you return as a list.  

Serializer.serialize is used to return entire querysets to json which you can pass back to your view template.

Comment: You guys are correct. I would have marked yours as correct answer if you had added in 'Answer' instead of comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`serializers.serialize` is for full querysets only. But `values` returns a container of dicts, so you can more or less pass that directly to `json.dumps` - all you need to do is convert the container itself to a list.

```
lists = Actor.objects.actor_like(query)
data = json.dumps(list(lists))
```

Comment: What if the dict contains a decimal?

Comment: Define a subclass of json serializer to convert datetime, decimal, etc. in the default method